# how to create role with policy attached with cloud formation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a lambda function that needs to talk to few aws services like (EC2, other lambda functions, api gateway, Elastic Search service). all of these services are inside a private subnet in an exsiting vpc. How do i add a policy/role via cloudformation template such that i give access my lambda function to communicate with these other services. also , do i need to define a security group. right now there is a default security group applied to all of resources which doesn't have any inbound/outbound rules.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters: 

  VPCId: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

Resources:
  # S3 Bucket
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  # Functions
  S3-Lambda-trigger:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Description: s3 object creation triggers lambda
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        S3Bucket:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
            Events: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'

  # Permissions
  Allow-lamda-invocation-s3:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref S3-Lambda-trigger
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt S3Bucket.Arn
```

Comment: Documentation for creating IAM roles in CloudFormation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.htm gives some example policy documents, which you will need to translate to YAML to use in your template.

Comment: [AWS::IAM::Role - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html)